# What are the advantages of inline?

Tags: actionscript-3, inline

I've been reading a bit about how to use the inline metadata when using the ASC 2.0 compiler.

However I can't find any source of info explaining why I should use them.

Anyone knows?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions induce overhead in any programming language.  Per ActionScript, when function execution begins, a number of objects and properties are created.

First, an *activation object* is created that stores the parameters and local variables declared in a function body.  It's an internal mechanism that cannot be directly accessed.

Second, a *scope chain* is created that contains an ordered list of objects that Flash platform checks for identifier declarations.  Every function that executes has a scope chain that is stored in an internal property.

Function closures maintain a snapshot of a function and its lexical environment.

Moving code inline reduces the creation of these objects, and how references are maintained on the stack.  Per Flash, you may see 4x performance increase.

Of course, there are tradeoffs - without the `inline` keyword induces code complexity; as well, inlining code increasing the amount of bytecode.  Besides larger applications, the virtual machine spends additional time verifying and JIT compiling.

Comment: I see, so like BotMaster said, I should use if possible the inline metadata on performance critical methods, right?. Like loops, or IA, or maybe physics too?.

Comment: It should be used only for small segments of code - `Math.abs()` is a good example of a function to be inlined.  Using inline _within_ loops is key, as that function is frequently being called.

Comment: Wait, but Math.abs is already a method. Where should I put my [inline] metadata?

Comment: It was used only as a example of small isolated segment of code.

Comment: Math builtin methods used in demanding loops are a good example of inline advantages. Since those method calls slow down code speed execution they can be replaced by custom methods (most of those math methods can be rewritten easily) to take advantage of inline.

Answer (score 1):

To simplify, inline is some sort of copy/paste of code. Since method calls are expensive and cost execution time, using inline keyword will copy/paste the body of the method each time the method call is present in your code so the method call will be replaced by the body of the method instead. Since this is done at compilation time it will increase in theory the size of the resulting app (if an inline method is called 10 times its body will be copied and pasted 10 times) but since all calls will be replaced you will gain speed execution. This is of course only relevant for demanding code execution like loops running at each frame for example.